# grid view multiple row selection with pagination

Tags: c#, gridview, pagination

I have a Gridview with three or more pages' worth of data. The user will check checkboxes in all these pages and click the submit button. The checked values in all the pages need to be stored in the database.

The problem is only the selected page's values got stored to the database and not the checked values on other pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Web Forms. I think pagination in a GridView causes a post back event, which means any state that isn't in the server side is lost.

You need to store which entries are checked in server state somehow (putting a Dictionary or List in the ViewState for example) either each time you check a box, or each time you page. Then, when you page, you should use the saved state to restore the check box values on the current page.